# Highlight product features image with css and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a product features page that highlights the area of an image and a corresponding description. I have opted to use divs with absolute positioning, instead of an image map. I have the page working, but my jquery is lacking and I would like to know the best way writing the following script?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#feature_1').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $('#feature_1_highlight').css('display', 'inherit');
    });
    $('#feature_1').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $('#feature_1_highlight').css('display', 'none');
    });
 
 $('#feature_2').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $('#feature_2_highlight').css('display', 'inherit');
    });
    $('#feature_2').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $('#feature_2_highlight').css('display', 'none');
    });
 
 $('#feature_3').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $('#feature_3_highlight').css('display', 'inherit');
    });
    $('#feature_3').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $('#feature_3_highlight').css('display', 'none');
    });
 
 $('#feature_4').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $('#feature_4_highlight').css('display', 'inherit');
    });
    $('#feature_4').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $('#feature_4_highlight').css('display', 'none');
    });
 
 $('#feature_5').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $('#feature_5_highlight').css('display', 'inherit');
    });
    $('#feature_5').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $('#feature_5_highlight').css('display', 'none');
    });
 
 $('#feature_6').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $('#feature_6_highlight').css('display', 'inherit');
    });
    $('#feature_6').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $('#feature_6_highlight').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

```css
.features_left, .woocommerce .features_right {
 width:295px;
 height:380px;
 float:left;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
 .features_heading {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:800;
  font-size:.8em;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:5px;
 }
 
 .features_desc {
  font-size:.8em;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:45px;
  line-height:1.5;
 }

.features_image {
 width:380px;
 height:380px;
 float:left;
 margin:0 20px;
 position:relative;
}
 .features_image img{
  width:380px;
 }
 .feature_highlight {
  position:absolute;
  width: 40px; 
  height: 40px; 
  background: rgba(206,65,37,0.50);
  border:4px solid #CE4125;
  -moz-border-radius: 20px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px; 
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index:10;
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="features_left">
 <div id="feature_1">
  <div class="features_heading highlight">Title 1</div>
   <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="feature_3">
     <div class="features_heading">Title 3</div>
     <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="feature_5">
     <div class="features_heading">Title 5</div>
     <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="features_image">
  
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/technics" >
        
    <div id="feature_1_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:50px; left:50px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_2_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:150px; left:100px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_3_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:200px; left:50px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_4_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:250px; left:150px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_5_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:50px; left:200px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_6_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:150px; left:150px;"></div>

</div>
<div class="features_right">
 <div id="feature_2">
  <div class="features_heading">Title 2</div>
     <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="feature_4">
     <div class="features_heading">Title 3</div>
     <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="feature_6">
     <div class="features_heading">Title 4</div>
     <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I included the HTML and CSS for reference. It is best to view full screen. (The image is randomly generated, so who knows what you will get!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is.

Since, on mouseover you want to highlight a particular feature and you know which element should highlight which features. I would add the targeted feature's id as part of the data-attribute like so.

```
<div class="features_left">
    <div class="feature" data-highlight="#feature_1_highlight">
        <div class="features_heading highlight">Title 1</div>
        <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature" data-highlight="#feature_2_highlight">
        <div class="features_heading">Title 3</div>
        <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature" data-highlight="#feature_3_highlight">
        <div class="features_heading">Title 5</div>
        <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="features_image">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/technics" >

    <div id="feature_1_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:50px; left:50px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_2_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:150px; left:100px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_3_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:200px; left:50px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_4_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:250px; left:150px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_5_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:50px; left:200px;"></div>
    <div id="feature_6_highlight" class="feature_highlight" style="top:150px; left:150px;"></div>

</div>
<div class="features_right">
    <div class="feature" data-highlight="#feature_4_highlight">
        <div class="features_heading">Title 2</div>
        <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature"  data-highlight="#feature_5_highlight">
        <div class="features_heading">Title 3</div>
        <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="feature" data-highlight="#feature_6_highlight">
        <div class="features_heading">Title 4</div>
        <div class="features_desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And now my javascript will look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.feature').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color', '#CE4125');
        $($(this).attr("data-highlight")).css('display', 'inherit');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find('.features_heading').css('color','#56534F');
        $($(this).attr("data-highlight")).css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devkickstart/qon475nx/)